# Get service name from ipaddress

Tags: docker

I would like to know if there's a way to find out within a running container the name of another service by its IP address (giving that they're connected on the same overlay network). I've tried to get it with ping and nslookup but it doesn't give any clue of the service name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run services in same (for example) swarm stack. Then within same stack you can access different container by service name (which is registered as DNS name)

Giving following test docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  service-a:
    image: busybox
  service-b:
    image: containous/whoami
```

Then when you login to bussybox and run `curl -vvv http://service-b` you'll get whoami "welcome" page output

Nice description of docker networking can be found [HERE](https://runnable.com/docker/docker-compose-networking)

Comment: The question asks whether, given an IP, you can figure out the service name. Your answer is the opposite of what was asked.

Comment: Omer is right, I'd like to know the service name from the IP address I think it can be used to help identify a caller.